# heroku and nuxt file uploader not working

Tags: heroku, save, storage, nuxt.js, multer

I have a PWA made with NuxtJS correctly deployed and working on Heroku.
I would like to implement a file uploader and manager so that I can manage some files in a directory `(~/static/files)` from my front-end through some APIs.
On localhost, it works fine so I have my directory and when I add or delete the file, it deletes or creates it from the file system (as it should).

My question is: why can't I do the same on Heroku? I mean, I tried by uploading a file and deleting it and it works but the problem comes when I restart the app (through `heroku ps:restart -a appname`) because when I do so it deletes the file as if it was saved in RAM and not onto the file system.

If I try to see the files in the directory where they should be through `heroku run bash -a appname` and then down to the directory, no file is showed.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a process known as "Cycling".

These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files).